# StationaRy error message

Tags: r

I'm trying to download station data using get_isd_station_data in StationaRy package and get the following error message:

> trying URL
>   'ftp:/ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/1980/946720-99999-1980.gz'
>   downloaded 31 KB
>
> trying URL
>   'ftp:/ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/1981/946720-99999-1981.gz'
>   downloaded 34 KB
>
> trying URL
>   'ftp:/ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/1982/946720-99999-1982.gz'
>   downloaded 31 KB
>
> trying URL
>   'ftp:/ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/1983/946720-99999-1983.gz'
>   downloaded 33 KB
>
> trying URL
>   'ftp:/ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/1984/946720-99999-1984.gz'
>   downloaded 33 KB
>
> trying URL
>   'ftp:/ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/1949/037720-99999-1949.gz'
>   downloaded 258 KB
>
> trying URL
>   'ftp:/ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/1950/037720-99999-1950.gz'
>   downloaded 263 KB
>
> trying URL
>   'ftp:/ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/1951/037720-99999-1951.gz'
>   downloaded 262 KB
>
> trying URL
>   'ftp:/ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/1952/037720-99999-1952.gz'
>   downloaded 261 KB
>
> trying URL
>   'ftp:/ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/1971/911820-22521-1971.gz'
>   downloaded 100 KB
>
> trying URL
>   'ftp:/ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/1972/911820-22521-1972.gz'
>   downloaded 103 KB
>
> trying URL
>   'ftp:/ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/1973/911820-22521-1973.gz'
>   downloaded 201 KB
>
> trying URL
>   'ftp:/ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/1974/911820-22521-1974.gz'
>   downloaded 228 KB
>
> trying URL
>   'ftp:/ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/1975/911820-22521-1975.gz'
>   downloaded 218 KB
>
> trying URL
>   'ftp:/ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/2002/747043-99999-2002.gz'
>   downloaded 117 KB
>
> trying URL
>   'ftp:/ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/2003/747043-99999-2003.gz'
>   downloaded 117 KB
>
> trying URL
>   'ftp:/ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/2004/747043-99999-2004.gz'
>   downloaded 122 KB
>
> trying URL
>   'ftp:/ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/2005/747043-99999-2005.gz'
>   downloaded 125 KB
>
> trying URL
>   'ftp:/ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/2006/747043-99999-2006.gz' Error
>   in if (file.info(file.path(temp_folder, data_file_to_download))$size >
>   :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed In addition: Warning
>   message: In download.file(url, ...) : InternetOpenUrl failed: ''

Some files have been successfully downloaded but I couldn't download from the station 747043-99999.

Can anyone help?

Note: I wasn't able to attach more than one links so I modified the message to not contain links.

Comment: if you try to open link throwing error `ftp:/ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/2006/747043-99999-2006.gz`, it shows `No such file or directory exists`, so i guess links are broken, raise a request in package repo

Comment: I couldn't attach more than 2 links so I modified them when posting. The link is: ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/2006/747043-99999-2006.‌​gz - sorry for the confusion. But you're right, the link is broken. The links for the other years work!